# Mocking static method doesn't work in newer mockito-core version

Tags: java, static, mockito, powermock

I'm experiencing strange error while changing `mockito-core` version. My code:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.validateMockitoUsage;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doNothing;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.verifyPrivate;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberMatcher.method;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(value = App.class)
public class TestClass {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockStatic(App.class);
        when(App.getInstance()).thenReturn(mock(App.class));
    }

    // tests
}
```

Mocking `App.getInstance()` works fine when i'm using

```
    testImplementation group:'org.mockito',name:'mockito-core',version:'2.23.0'
```

But changing that to newest version

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.28.2'
```

Gives me error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: Argument should be a mock, but is: class java.lang.Class
```

On line `when(App.getInstance()).thenReturn(mock(App.class));`

My build.gradle mockito part:

```
testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.28.2'
testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.2'
testImplementation group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.2'
```

Could anyone provide any ideas why changing `mockito-core` is causing this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could anyone provide any ideas why changing mockito-core is causing this issue?

Sure: PowerMock(ito) doesn't just work with *any* version of Mockito.

See their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#supported-versions):

```
Mockito PowerMock
2.8.9+  2.x
```

See that. 2.8.something. Not 2.**28**.something

You are simply lucky that 2.23 works, as that version is **also** not supported.

Another good reason to be really cautious about buying into the PowerMock dependency: it significantly reduces your ability to use newer versions of Mockito.

Thus my personal two cent: the only reasonable use case for PowerMock(ito) is when you have legacy code that can't be tested otherwise. For *any* other project, especially when writing your own, new code: simply use standalone Mockito. And instead of using the PowerMock hammer to test hard-to-test code, spend some time to learn how to write easy-to-test code.

Long story short: when using PowerMock, you better stick to versions of Mockito that have the "official" approval by Team PowerMock.

If you don't like to be restricted in such ways, I think I told you how to get out of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though that 2.28.2 is was applicable for 2.8.9+, guess not :). Appreciate your personal opinion, unfortunately it's not my project. I was just experimenting how could we verify private methods and mock static methods.

Comment: @Mershel For private methods, you can always look into the Mockito Spy concept. But yes, for *static* stuff, PowerMock(ito) or JMockit are inevitable.

Comment: @GhostCat WHat do you mean with 4th paragraph?

Comment: The one that talks about the only reasonable use for PowerMock ‍♂️